# TypeScript pixi.js

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

I did: 
`npm install pixi.js`,
`tsd install pixi.js`,
I have correctly implemented everything, except the definitions file from tsd has 
comment

```
//Type definitions for Pixi.js v3.0.10-dev
```

and my dist `.js` file is also:

```
//pixi.js - v3.0.9 (this version mismatch is not critical)
```

So, my question is, is there some list of changes between "Examples" published [on the pixi.js website](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/) and this version (v3.x.x)?

(The most difficult for me is to google it, because tons of stuff in smartphones is named PIXI v2/v3, and additionally I am developer of mobile apps, so for example my filter `--Actacel` is way too weak [Actacel Pixi 2, 3 comparision comes out] #HateMyGoogleProfiling :) )

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `./node_modules/pixi.js/src/deprecation.js` is my answer.

If anyone still has problems - just ctrl-f find the names.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [@types/pixi.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pixi.js)
which has the most up to date typescript info on the 4.X branch. 
Most of the examples are bound to `@latest` so if you're building off the examples I'd use the newer typescript definitions.